# How can I implement interface correctly?

Tags: java, methods, interface, compiler-errors, abstract

I am doing homework of making a simple calculator using java and interface in java. but the class that implements java gives error saying

```
The public type `BasicCalculator` must be defined in its own file
        The type `BasicCalculator` must implement the inherited abstract method `calculate.mul(int, int)
```

here is the code

```
interface calculate{
    public int add(int a, int b);
    public int sub(int a, int b);
    public int mul(int a, int b);
    public int div(int a, int b);
}

public class BasicCalculator implements calculate { 
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int subtract(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }

    public int multiply(int a, int b) {
        return a * b;
    }

    public int division(int a, int b){
        return a/b;
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculate c= new BasicCalculator();
        c.add(5,6);
    }
}
```

Comment: What of the error message is unclear? It says it pretty much, you have to put `BasicCalculator` in its own file and have it implement `mul`, and not `multiply`. The same is true for all the other methods

Comment: Your int division will drop fractions.  Is that what you want?  And to ensure you are implementing correctly put @Override before each method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

First, since `BasicCalculator` is a public class, it needs to be defined in its own file named `BasicCalculator.java`.

Second, the method names in `BasicCalculator` must match those you're trying to implement in `calcualte` - i.e., `sub`, `mul` and `div` instead of `subtract`, `multiply` and `division`.

Comment: hits the problem. It is solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Send the test class onto it's own class and not in the same class as BasicCalculator.java, because java usually doesn't like to deal with classes this way unlike C.

Then add @Override on top of each method that you have implemented so the code will go as:

```
 @Override
public int div(int a, int b) {
    return 0;
}
```

like this for example.

The thing that is happening here is since you are implementing your interface you need to have all the methods inside the class that you are implementing in.

And at the end when you run test.java, add System.out.println(c.add(5, 6));
for example since return x;
doesn't print the actual value on the console.